# How to pick set of random values from property file using Java?

Tags: java

I have a Property file called `test.properties` in `C:\Test\` Directory.

In the Property file i have *property ID* and *Property* values as follows:

```
TestID=Test1,Test2,Test3,Tes4 upto 10
```

By using Java code how can i pick any 5 random values from the property file and then need to verify the those values are available in the **FE**.

I'm beginner of ***Java*** please help me with some sample code

Comment: `id` and `value` are key value pairs. property files are meant for using the same value throughout the application

Comment: i'm totally collapsed where which need to come.. ould anyone please give me a follow of code i can understand the logic. If possible please anyone can implement with the above code

Answer (score 0):

This should shuffle all the elements of an array

```
String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
  Random r = new Random();
  for (int i = expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     int index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
     String temp = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i];
     expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i] = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[index];
     expectedDropDownItemsInArray[index] = temp;
  }
  System.out.println(expectedDropDownItemsInArray);
```

Then as usual

```
ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);
```

Comment: int index = r.nextInt(0,i);string temp = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i];expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i] = index; The method nextInt(int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int, int), string cannot be resolved to a type, Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String. These error am getting

Comment: @user3496643, i have updated the code. I was typing pseudo code.
Understanding the logic is important.

Comment: String temp = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]; It is showing error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
 at test.DD.FilterMatching(DD.java:57)

Comment: how will check pick the values from property file.. IS that you will load the property file or in which line are you picking the values from the property file can you explain it

Comment: I just added extra code to your logic. You need to load properties as per your code and then shuffle the array elements for randomization.

Comment: yes i can able to load by using this line Properties APPTEXT = new Properties();
Log.info("Getting Input from the Property file");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\FilterSection\\dropdown.properties");
APPTEXT.load(fs);
System.out.println ("" +APPTEXT); but the problem how will you pick. In which line are you picking value from the property file

Comment: You have coded for that already `String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = APPTEXT.getProperty("TestId").trim().split(",");
`

Comment: yes but the problem nothing is happen with that line.. Please check the edited code which i have added  now

Comment: I'm getting output for the above code which i have added is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
 at test.DD.FilterMatching(DD.java:57)

Comment: Can you check the code again? it's working fine with sample data.

Comment: i have checked pls check my code what mistakes i have done or could able to give the entire sample code for this scenario which you have verified

Comment: yes i have verified and the output is [Ljava.lang.String;@796e41d1 but where are you picking from the property file. You are giving as string directly but in my case it need to check the property Id then for that ID i need to pick the random values

Comment: What I am suggesting you is, pick all the values of key from property file, then shuffle them and pick as many elements as you want as they are already randomized

Comment: @ Reddy Fine i can get your concepts. But I'm learning java now only if possible what ever you are telling please give as a sample code so that i will execute and then i will understand

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not have too many properties in your file, do it this way:

```
// Define your file here !
private static final File PROPERTIES_FILE = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileReader(PROPERTIES_FILE));
    ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>(properties.entrySet());
    while (values.size() > 5) values.remove((int) (Math.random() * values.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have all the items in a List (assuming `expectedDropDownItems` is a `java.util.List`.

You can select 5 random entries from this list like this:

First, shuffle the list:

```
Collections.shuffle(expectedDropDownItems);
```

Now the list is in random order, just take the first five entries and put them in a new list:

```
List<String> randomFive = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   if (i < expectedDropDownItems.size() {
       randomFive.add(expectedDropDownItems.get(i));
   }
}
```